# Server errors displayed instead of loading data from database

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax, http-status-code-500

I don't know what I'm missing. I'm trying to load data from database into the navbar. Navbar should have different links for administrators, signed users and other users. Since I didn't make page for sign in and sign up yet, I assumed that the code from page showMenu.php called with AJAX will take last function loaded from functions.php which is a query for not signed in users. But instead of getting data back from the database to write with JS, the code fall into error property of AJAX call and in addition to that displays server error 500 for showMenu.php page. I checked all the paths for both main.js and php pages and names of tables and columns in database and everything is correct. And just for the record, connection.php includes fetch mode, so columns of tables can be accessed with ->. What do I'm missing.

js code

```
getViaAjax("showMenu",showMenu);
function getViaAjax(fileName, specificFunction) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "models/" + fileName + ".php",
    method: "get",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(jsonData){
      specificFunction(jsonData);
   },
    error: function(xhr){
      console.error(xhr);
   }
  });
}
function showMenu(menuJsonData){
    let writingMenu = "";
    menuJsonData.forEach(partOfMenu=>{
        writingMenu+=`<li id="${partOfMenu.id}" class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="${partOfMenu.href}">${partOfMenu.label}</a>
        </li>`;
    });
    document.getElementById("menu").innerHTML=writingMenu;
}
```

showMenu.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET'){
        include "../config/connection.php";
        include "functions.php";

        try{
            if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
                $user = $_SESSION['user'];
                if($user->roleId==1){
                    $jsonMenu = showMenuForAdmin();
                }
                else {
                    $jsonMenu = showMenuForSignedInUser();
                }
            }
            else{
                $jsonMenu = showMenuForNonSignedInUser();
            }
            echo json_encode($jsonMenu);
            http_response_code(200);
        }
        catch(PDOException $exception){
            http_response_code(500);
        }
    }
    else{
        http_response_code(404);
    }
?>
```

function from functions.php I want to be triggered when user not registered or signed

```
function showMenuForNonSignedInUser(){
        global $connection;
        $query = "SELECT id, href, label WHERE id NOT LIKE 6;";
        $data = $connection->query($query)->fetchAll();
        return $data;
    }
```

Comment: If you're getting a 500 status then your server logs should contain details of the error.

Comment: Also note your SQL doesn't have a `FROM table` in it.

Comment: You'd have to check your database docs and maybe run an explain, but I imagine that `NOT LIKE 6` isn't going to be a indexable query, you may want to use `!= 6` instead. Or better, add a column like `ACTIVE` that you can toggle so that you don't need to hardcode exceptions like this.

Comment: Alex Howansky, thanks a lot!